# Adding a line to the start of a file, based on other lines in the file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, awk

I have files of the following structure:

```
foo.bar.baz () ->
  templateUrl: require('x.jade')
```

I need to transform these files such that:

1. They are prefixed with the line `var templateUrl = require('x.jade')`
2. The `templateUrl:` line is replaced with `templateUrl: templateUrl`.

How can I do this? One option is a bash script that, for each file:

1. `grep`s for `templateUrl:` to get the `require` part.
2. `cat`s the `var templateUrl` line and the file together into a new file, and then replaces the original file.
3. Uses `sed` to replace `templateUrl: require...` with `templateUrl`.

But can this be done with a single `sed` or `awk` script that can be executed for each file?

Comment: Excuse me if I didn't understand, see if this sed does what you want `sed -n '1h;:a;n;s/require/&/;tInsert;H;ba;:Insert;H;s/^/var/;s/:/ =/;G;s/: .*/: templateUrl/;p'`

Comment: @Paulo Nice `sed` solution. Please post it as an answer possibly adding some explanations.

Comment: @simlev because I've been on holiday, I'm just catching up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@simlev's `perl` solution really has less steps, but I'd like to present my `sed` command. It is more relevant because the OP already envisioned using `sed` and explicitly asks for a `sed` or `awk` script.

```
sed -n '1h;:a;n;s/require/&/;tInsert;H;ba;:Insert;H;s/^/var/;s/:/ =/;G;s/: .*/: templateUrl/;p'
```

**Note:** This command will not work if the file contains more than one line with `:` or `require`.

**Explanation:**

```
sed -n        # -n option disables automatic printing.

1 h           # h command puts the first line (address 1) in the hold space,
              # replacing any previous content.

:a            # Set a mark with label 'a'.

n             # n command prints the pattern space and loads next line of input,
              # replacing all pattern space content.
              # But it will not print because of -n option.

s/require/&/  # Test if the pattern space has the line OP wants edit.

t Insert      # If substitution was made, t command jumps to the mark with label 'Insert'.

H             # If not, continue with H command, it appends a '\n' to the hold space content
              # and then appends the pattern space to the hold space.

b a           # b (branch) command, jumps to the mark with label 'a'.

:Insert       # Exit from the 'a' loop. Here the hold space has all the lines that precede
              # the line with 'replace', and pattern space has the line with 'replace'.
H             # The line with 'replace' is appended to the hold space too.

s/^/var/      # Here sed finally edits the line, replacing the beginning with 'var' ...

s/:/ =/       # and only the first ':' with ' ='.

G             # G command appends the content of hold space to the edited pattern space,
              # here that line edited above in pattern space becomes the first line.

s/: .*/: templateUrl/    # One more substitution.

p'            # Finally, print the pattern space.
```

Comment: I agree with _simlev_ edition, he cleaned the explanation adding comments indentation and improved my English. Also one can see my original answer by clicking at `edited` below the answer. I'm still learning how to use SuperUser interface :)

Answer (score 2):

Input file(s):

```
foo.bar.baz () ->
  templateUrl: require('x.jade')
```

`perl` command:

```
perl -i -0777pe '$_=~s/templateUrl:( \K.*)/templateUrl/;print"var templateUrl =$1\n"' *
```

Output file(s):

```
var templateUrl = require('x.jade')
foo.bar.baz () ->
  templateUrl: templateUrl
```

**Breakdown:**

- `perl` scripting language that excels at text manipulation
- `-i` edit files in-place
- `-0777` work with the file as a whole, as opposed to line-by-line
- `p` print the file (in this case the file will be saved, due to the `-i` switch)
- `e` execute the following command, as opposed to executing code that is saved in a file
- `'` start of instructions
- `$_=~s` perform a substitution on the entire file (`$_`)
- `/templateUrl:( \K.*))/` look for a line matching the regex `templateUrl: .*`, and capture the string matching the parenthesised subexpression  `.*` to a variable (called `$1` by default)
- `templateUrl/` replace the part after the `\K` marker in the matched line with text `templateUrl`
- `;` separates between instructions
- `print"var templateUrl =$1\n"` print `var templateUrl =`, the contents of `$1` and a newline
- at this point, the rest of the file is implicitly printed, because the `p` switch was specified
- `'` end of instructions
- `*` process every file in the current directory

There can be of course different approaches, such as:

```
perl -i -ne 'if ($_=~s/templateUrl:( \K.*)/templateUrl/){$a="templateUrl =$1"} {$file.=$_} END{print"var $a\n$file"}' *
```

**AWK**:
Since the question is about `sed` or `awk`, it is worth noting that either approach can be just as easily implemented in `awk`:

```
awk -i 'BEGIN {RS="\0"} {match($0,/templateUrl:( .*)/,m); gsub("templateUrl: .*","templateUrl: templateUrl"); print "var templateUrl ="m[1]$0}' *
```

```
awk -i '/templateUrl: / {a="templateUrl = "$2;gsub("templateUrl: .*","templateUrl: templateUrl")} NR==1 {file=$0} NR==2{file=file"\n"$0} END{print a"\n"file}' *
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could accept both answers, both are very enlightening.